# Can I pass handle function as props to other screen in Router?

Tags: javascript, react-native

everyone.
I am learning React-native and I faced a problem.
I want to pass handle function as props to other screen in routes when I am executing function Actions.about().

Below is my Routes code.

```
<Router>
    <Scene key = "root">
        <Scene key = "home" component = {Home} title = "Home" initial = {true} />
        <Scene key = "about" component = {About} title = "About" />
        <Scene key = "login" component = {Login} title = "LOG IN" />
    </Scene>
</Router>
```

And this is my function.

```
function handleConfirm(value) {
    Actions.about(handleDo = this.handleDo);
}
```

Then I want to access this **handleDo** in Actions component.
Let us imagine **this.handleDo** is for changing some state values in Home component.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Which navigation library you use?

Comment: This is import code.
```import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux'```

Comment: I think a bit more context and maybe a reproducible code sample would've been helpful here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Actions.about({ param1: 'hello', param2: 'world' });
```

in about

```
this.props.param1//return hello
```

Comment: What's exactly Actions.about() it's provided from react navigation?